# Local workgroup size = NULL OpenCL

Tags: opencl

Is there a way to get the used local workgroup size, when you set the value of the local workgroup size in the enqueueNDRangeKernel() function to NULL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard runtime API for doing this in OpenCL. If you really need to know, you could have the kernel retrieve the work-group size with the `get_local_size()` function and store the value(s) to a buffer.

The vendor profilers (AMD's CodeXL, Intel's VTune, NVIDIA's command-line profiler) should also tell you what they picked.