# OpenCL get used work group size

Tags: c, opencl

In OpenCL, how can I know the exact size of the local work group during the runtime? clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo seems only return you the maximum possible size, see https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo.html

CL_KERNEL_COMPILE_WORK_GROUP_SIZE of the above documents will give (0,0,0) if you haven't specified the size.

Comment: Maybe this link will help You:
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0538e/BABFIGJE.html

"If your application is not required to share data among work-items, set the local_work_size parameter to NULL when enqueuing your kernel. This enables the OpenCL driver to determine the most efficient work-group size for your kernel."

also this link would be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496681/is-clgetkernelworkgroupinfo-cl-kernel-work-group-size-the-size-opencl-uses-whe

Comment: @Tadek Thanks. So basically it means the program will choose for you when compiled. There is no way to know what is this 'determined' size?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Local workgroup size = NULL OpenCL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28811839/local-workgroup-size-null-opencl)

Answer (score 0):

You may query maximal available size of work group with  clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo:

```
size_t max_available_local_wg_size;
cl_int ret = clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo(kernel, device_id, CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, sizeof(size_t),                 &max_available_local_wg_size, NULL);
```

Though, if you don't set the value by hand, implementation will choose it by itself. Usually, you can get actual work group size with profiler, which comes with OpenCL SDK from vendor.